# HTML5 audio tag dynamic src ajax it does not play

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-programming, html5-audio

I am working with Ajax getting the audio source from the data base. I successful took the data but the problem is it does not play.

```
<label>balay</label>
<audio id="audio" src="" type="audio/wav">
```

this is the HTML

```
$('label').hover(function(){
var ex = $(this).html();
$.post('../php/fetchAudiosrc.php' , {input:ex} , function(data){
    $('#audio').attr("src", data);
    $('#audio').get(0).play();
}
```

I dont need to show the fetchAudiosrc.php because it return the correct data. the problem is the audio does not really play.

Comment: try `$('#audio').play();`

Comment: You can't set directly the raw data of an audio media into the audio's src, you'll have either to transform it to a blobURI (`audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], 'audioMIMEType'));` or to use a native `XMLHttpRequest` with its `.responseType` set to `'blob'`, or to make it a dataURI `audio.src = 'data:audio/audioType, base64'+ btoa(data)`. But the easiest is still to leave the ajax call away and directly set the audio src to the correct url.

Comment: @Azzi i tried that. already.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm sorry I'm just beginner for this. I don't understand the blob or dataURI. but what I know is set the audio src directly. I'm making a lot of pages using this code that is why is need it to be dynamic.

Comment: if you try to `console.log(data)` you'll see that it's the raw data of your file. The browser can't just use it as the source of an audio element. You have to convert it. [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) can represent a file. You can either create one from the data, or ask the xhr itself to return a blob directly. You can then make a blobURI thanks to the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) API.

Comment: Or you can use [dataURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) which lets the browser know that what follows is some data.

Comment: @Kaiido can you show me how to use this sir?

Comment: @Kaiido did I just close the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is inside a folder so I concatenate the scr witg ../  sorry for disturbing. and thank you for dropping by.

```
$('label').hover(function(){
var ex = $(this).html();
$.post('../php/fetchAudiosrc.php' , {input:ex} , function(data){
    $('#audio').attr("src", '../'+data);
    $('#audio').get(0).play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="card-body" onclick="setFooterPlayerSourse(this)">
    <data value="AudioID"></data>
    <h6 class="card-title">Artist</h6>
    <h7 class="card-text">Composition</h7>
</div>

<div id="player-audio-div" >
    <audio id="player-audio-element" controls="controls" height="80" width="100%">
        <source id="player-source-element" src="null" type="audio/mp3" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

**onclick="setFooterPlayerCourse(this)"** is inserted into a "div" that has the audio ID in it's data

```js
function setFooterPlayerSourse(el)
{
    try {
        // <data value="AudioID"></data>
        let audio_id = el.children[0].value;
        // https://localhost:5001/GetHtmlPlayer/?id=1
        let ctrl = (el.baseURI + 'GetHtmlPlayer/?id=' + audio_id);
        if ($("#player-source-element") != undefined) {
            $.ajax({ //$.get({ 
                url: ctrl,
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'html',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('Ajax returned: ' + response);
                    $("#player-audio-div").html('');
                    $("#player-audio-div").append(response);
                    plr = $("#player-audio-element").get(0);
                    plr.play();
                },
                error: function (error_) {
                    console.log("Ajax error: " + error_);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e)
    }
}
```